# How to automate migration (schema and data) for PHP/MySQL application

Tags: php, mysql, deployment, migration

I have an application in PHP/MySQL. I am searching for an automated way upgrading database behind the application.
I don't need to have the compatibility with older versions once it is upgraded.

I have read [jeff's](https://blog.codinghorror.com/get-your-database-under-version-control/) and [K. Scott Allen's](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2008/02/03/11746.aspx) articles on this.

I am still not sure how to implement this for a PHP/MySQL application.

Is there any simple and good process for this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have a "Schema" object that I use - but you could do the same without classes..

What you want to do is create a '`db_schema_versions`' table:

```
CREATE TABLE db_schema_versions (
  `table` varchar(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
  `version` INT NOT NULL
)
```

After your database can track what version # it is on - it can do SQL upgrades automatically.

You should lock your schema table while upgrading schema.  This way you wont have two requests at the same moment trying to upgrade your schema.

So - keep track of the version you are upgrading from - build a big switch - something like this:

```
class SNTrack_Db_Schema extends MW_Db_Schema_Abstract {
  protected $table = "sntrack_db_schema";
  protected $version = 5;

  protected function upgrade($fromVersion) {
    // don't break
    switch($fromVersion) {
      case 0:
        $this->db->query('CREATE TABLE sntrack_inbound_shipment (
            `id` INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
            `from` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            `date` DATE NOT NULL,
            `invoice` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            `notes` TEXT
          )');
        $this->setVersion(1);
      case 1:
        $this->db->query('ALTER TABLE sntrack_details ADD `shipment_id` INT');
        $this->db->query('ALTER TABLE sntrack_product ADD `inventory` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0');
        $this->db->query('CREATE TABLE sntrack_inventory_shipment (
            `shipment_id` INT NOT NULL,
            `product_id` INT NOT NULL,
            `qty` INT NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (`shipment_id`, `product_id`)
          )');
        $this->setVersion(2);
...etc
```

Comment: if user is upgrading from version 2 to version 6.  Would you iterate over each version 2-6 and run each SQL in the switch 2,3,4,5, and 6 so that each upgrade in the switch is just the sql to upgrade from the previous version?

Answer (score 4):

Try to use this tool for schema migration: https://github.com/idler/MMP/

Comment: I've merged your registered and unregistered accounts so you have full control over your posts.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to gnarf's suggestion I would run with the following:

- For every change to the schema create an SQL file that when run will take you from the old version to the new version (this could be one file per major version or lots of smaller changes).
- Create a separate file listing each of the SQL file names in the order they must be applied in (oldest at the top, newest at the bottom)
- Create a simple "versioning" table (all it needs is a single VARCHAR column) in your database

Now you need to write a simple script that works in the following way:

- Query the versioning table for the name of the last SQL update file applied
- If there are newer SQL alteration files to be run execute them in sequence
- record the name of the newest SQL file applied

I hope that makes sense

Comment: +1 for good logic. But how do you execute the sql files from PHP?
SOURCE file.sql does not work with mysqli_real_query!
Or how do you script?

Comment: Perhaps you'd have to explode on ; to find statements (but this would be easy to break).

Some kind of not nice implementation of `cat /some/deployment-file.sql | mysql ...` could be used

Answer (score 2):

I created a tiny migration script for MySQL in PHP. It's good for early-stage projects and those not needing (yet) the more complex migration scripts. https://github.com/kennberg/php-mysql-migrate

Answer (score 0):

One way you can go about it is to dump the database into a large sql file using mysqldump. Just take that file and source it within the new installation.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You either

1. Write update files with all sql's that were executed on source enviroment and then execute them (mentioned above), SVN-like. Need php script for execution and manual work for sql writing
2. Post-analyze both enviroments and suggest to user which updates should be migrated. Basically same thing as the first one, except that you have one big step for migration, not lots of small chunks. SQLyog can analyze diffrences for both schema and data.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a free API [SqlQuerySync](https://www.sqlquerysync.com)

or create for yourself a database table managing CREATE / ALTER / DELETE queries.

Answer (score 0):

Use migratedb https://github.com/malukenho/MigrateDB from @malukenho

Answer (score 0):

MySQL bench software (could be found on the mysql website) does that. It involves repetitive clicky steps though.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same goal : migrating a big database (more than a million lines in some tables). I am considering to use https://phinx.org wich seems good to deal with the schema migration, in addition it comes with rollback option for safety.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this library out: [mysql-version-control](https://github.com/smrtr/mysql-version-control).

I like this one because it differentiates between schema, core data and test data. But does it in a way that's still really easy to use.