# How to make a python package public if it relies on a SQL database I used?

Tags: python, mysql, database, package, public

So my data is stored in a mySQL database (on a local server).  Im wondering what are the steps I need to complete in order to make the package available to other users?  Like from GitHub?  Since the package relies on the database content, I assume public users wouldn't be able to use the package.  Or would they?  Sorry I'm really new to this, so I am really unsure of the procedures.

Comment: Check out [How to include MySQL database schema on Github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16288579/how-to-include-mysql-database-schema-on-github)

Answer (score 1):

Your best best is ship the package with the following:

- **fixtures** which will contain data you application needs
- **script** to insert the "fixtures" in the user of your package

#### fixtures

There are many ways to do this. I personally like how [Django does fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/initial-data/#providing-initial-data-with-fixtures) as they are simple json files. Alternatively you can supply "fixtures" as SQL scripts, model instances, etc.

#### script

The purpose of  the script is to install the fixtures packaged within your project in the database. It will essentially read the fixture data in whatever format you decide to store it, loop over it and insert in the configured database.

#### package

You will need to include some additional configurations in your `setup.py` in order for your package to include both the fixture files as well as the insert script:

- [data files](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-package-data):

  ```
  setup(...,
      package_data={'mypkg': ['data/*.json']},
  )
  ```
- [script file](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-scripts):

  ```
  setup(...,
      scripts=['scripts/fixture_load.py']
  )
  ```

Then when users will install your package (e.g. `pip install examplepackage`), it will install `fixture_load.py` script within the users Python environment which they will run to insert the fixture data.

Comment: Are there any resources where I can learn more about this as this is my first time attempting this.

Comment: I'm just a bit confused about fixtures in general since its my the first time hearing about them.

Comment: The answer includes a link to Django fixtures. That might get you started

Comment: Ok so after reading it I have a few questions.  From my understanding, I would need to install django in order to make use of their manage.py dumpdata command.  It seems to be the simplest way to dump data from database to a file in json format (default).  Now after the data is dumped in a file, why would we want to insert it into a database after ?  Does this mean the user needs to have a mysql database server on their system ?  I was intending to write a few functions that perform a number of tasks using the database, and then give the user these functions.